# Windows Phone 8 SQL Server CE An overflow occurred while converting to datetime

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to insert a record into a SQL Server CE database with linq to sql. Here's the code:

```
MedAidMember memberToInsert = new MedAidMember();
memberToInsert.Id = row.Mem_ID;
memberToInsert.memSchemeId = row.Mem_Sch_ID;
memberToInsert.BenefitDate = new DateTime(2008,08,08,1,12,33);

context.MedAidMembers.InsertOnSubmit(memberToInsert);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

When

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```

is hit I get the exception

> An overflow occurred while converting to datetime.

Have read this link that states SQL Server CE's datetime bounds:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

but I don't understand why that would be an issue with regards to what I want to insert.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Does the MedAidMember class have other datetime columns?

Comment: Probably. Looks like there's a date `0001-01-01` involved, or a nullable datetime with null value.

Comment: @ErikEJ Thank you!! Yes, this was the issue there was another date time that I missed, because that was not assigned a value, the error was thrown. I do wish that they would give a better error message though ...

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other datetime columns in your class...